# How to Make a Dialog Modal

Tags: c#, .net, dialog, xna, modal-dialog

I have a [save file dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog) set up to display but when I click off of it the dialog it disappears into the background without a tab or anything. My question is how do I make the dialog modal? If you don't know what I mean go into notepad hit save as and try to click off the dialog. You will see the window flashes and you get a nice sound informing you that you must do something in the dialog before doing anything else. I would like to achieve this effect with my dialog but I don't know how. I cannot simply use the [Form.Modal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.modal.aspx) property because that deals with forms and this isn't a Form. Could someone help me out here?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is how I'm showing the dialog, it's running in XNA and when I click the save as button the `EntrySelected()` method is called:

```
    private void EntrySelected(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(sender == saveAsEntry) {
            sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            thread = new Thread(ShowSaveDialog);
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }
        ...
    }
    private void ShowSaveDialog() {
        if(sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
            World.Save(sfd.FileName);
            thread.Abort();
        }
        else {
            thread.Abort();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to show a bit of code.  The save file dialog is already modal as can be seen by running the sample in the link you have.  So I'm a little curious as to how you got around that.

Comment: question, if you want it Modal why are you running it in a seperate thread?

Comment: If I don't I get a ThreadStateExeption. I'm guessing it has to do with XNA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualy your Dialog is a Form, As the above comment suggests there is not a Show method, you should be using ShowDialog() Command that opens it up as a Modal Dialog.

i.e.

```
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

---

Base on your edit, there is a version of [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a55b9ds) where you assign the owner to the Dialog, maybe that will work for you.

```
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog(dialogOwner);
```

From above link:

> This version of the ShowDialog method allows you to specify a specific form or control that will own the dialog box that is shown. If you use the version of this method that has no parameters, the dialog box being shown would be owned automatically by the currently active window of your application.